# LINQ filter collection by filed in it's subcollection

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have defined below classes:

```
public class AssignmentDictionaryDTOChildItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class AssignmentDictionaryDTO
{
    public string BatchName { get; set; }
    public List<AssignmentDictionaryDTOChildItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
```

and have a model as list of AssignmentDictionaryDTO type.

Now I want to filter my model by text field (from AssignmentDictionaryDTOChildItem)

```
model = model.Where( x => x.ChildItems.SelectMany( y => y.text.ToLower().Contains( q ), z => z ) );
```

but it does not compile - throws below exception

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TCollection,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TCollection>>, System.Func<TSource,TCollection,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

I know, that z in above query is of type AssignmentDictionaryDTOChildItem and my model is list of types AssignmentDictionaryDTO so it does not fit.
So how can I fix my query to achieve filtering I mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
model = model.Where(x => x.ChildItems.All(y => y.text.ToLower().Contains(q))).ToList();
//or Any instead of All
```